# How to break out of an inner loop back to an outer loop?

Tags: c#, loops, break, nested-loops

I have 4 entities"

ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC, ObjectD

```
foreach(ObjectA objectA in listObjectA)
if (relationAB)
  foreach(ObjectB objectB in listObjectB) 
  if (relationBC)   
    foreach(ObjectC objectC in listObjectC) 
    if (relationCD)   
      foreach(ObjectD objectD in listObjectD) 
        if (I found what I'm looking for)  
        Do something
```

So, when I will found what I wass looking for, I want to go to the first line, to the first for, but to the second element from the list. How can I do this? Whit goto?

Later Edit: This question is for C#.

P.S. Could you think a better way to do what I'm trying to do, whithout using 4 fors?

Comment: On the PS, are the lists related in some way that would require this quad-embedding? In your toy example, I don't see why they couldn't be 4 separate searches.

Answer (score 7):

Well, since this is just a "programming languages" question, the general answer would be to use your language's facility for naming loops, and then put the proper name on the "break" statement.

Sadly, I don't think the current versions of C and C++ support such a thing, so you would indeed have to resort to a `goto` when using them. A good way to avoid that would be to put the loop you want to break out of into its own subroutine, and just do a `return` when you are done instead of a `break`. That's what I generally do when working in those poor languages.

Your revised example would be:

```
void find_whatever (/* probably pass in the lists or objects to search for*/)
  foreach(ObjectA objectA in listObjectA)
    if (relationAB)
      foreach(ObjectB objectB in listObjectB) 
        if (relationBC)   
          foreach(ObjectC objectC in listObjectC) 
            if (relationCD)   
              foreach(ObjectD objectD in listObjectD) 
                if (I found what I'm looking for)  
                Do something
                return;
```

Note: The tag was changed from "programming languages" to "C#". That was the right thing to do for the question, but a lot of people liked this answer so I'm not making major mods to it.

Comment: C and C++ aren't poor just because they don't support labeled breaks ;-)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see the difference with the original code. Your `return` statement leaves the method `find_whatever` in stead of continuing with the next `objectA`.

Comment: Oh, yes. We must avoid `goto` at all cost! We wouldn't want to use such an evil language feature, even if it's appropriate for the task at hand. No, it's much better to obfuscate the code by spreading control flow out over multiple functions, using global variables,  passing lots of parameters, and peppering the code with silly things like `if (found) break;`

Comment: @Jim Mischel - Actually I'm with you. For applications like finite state machines, gotos are the *clearest* implementation. Today's anti-goto hate is a drastic overraction to its abuse in the olden days. However, in this case I think clarity is generally best-served by using a subroutine.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the language, you can generally add break labels. I'd avoid this, however, and suggest the following:

```
function main() {
    foreach (ObjectA a in listA) {
        if (relationAB) {
            processA(a)
        }
    }
}

function processA(ObjectA a) {
    foreach (b) {
        foreach (c) {
            foreach (d) {
                if (found) {
                    doSomething();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be hard to read code that has break labels and gotos. Breaking it into functions can make it easier to read and (probably) easier to write and debug.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to put it all in a function and use the `return` statement instead of the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `return` in such cases.

Just put some of your inner `for` in a method and return from it when necessary. It will be much more readable then a chain of

```
if (found) {
 break;
}
```

inside your loops.